# "nohup python3 .. &" ends once I disconnect from a server

Tags: debian, ssh, python, background-process, nohup

This command

```
nohup python3 main.py > my_log.log 2>&1 &
```

will end once I disconnect from a server.  That is, if I disconnect and then connect 10 seconds later, the task, or a job, will be gone.

However, if I stay on a server, it continues to work as long as it needs, with no problem.

Why? How to make it work in background even after I disconnect?

It's an AWS Debian server.

Comment: Can't explain the "why" part off the top of my head - hence the comment and not an answer, but it's common to run the apps you want to remain persistent from a `tmux` or `screen` session to avoid that kind of behavior.

Comment: @undercat my question is about `nohup`